# PHP MYSQL Clear cart data from database if checkout is successful

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart

i am trying to clear/delete the cart data from my database if the checkout is successful.

this is the form on my website
[image]

and this is the process of the **CONTINUE TO CHECKOUT BUTTON**

```html
<?php
function emptyCart(){
    // delete query
    $cID = $_SESSION['cID'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE customer_id = $cID";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
 
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }
 
    return false;
}

if (isset($_POST['checkout-submit'])) {
    $cID = $_POST['customer_id'];
    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $order_Fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['order_Fname']);
    $order_Lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['order_Lname']);
    $order_name = $order_Fname .' '. $order_Lname;

    $order_number = 'PSAU000';

    $order_phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['order_phone']);
    $order_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['order_email']);

    $order_Addrs = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['order_Addrs']);
    $order_Addrs2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['order_Addrs2']);
    $pro = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pro']);
    $mun = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mun']);
    $bar = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['bar']);
    $order_address = $order_Addrs .', '. $order_Addrs2 .', '. $pro .', '. $mun .', '. $bar;
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (order_number, order_name, order_phone, order_email, order_address, order_date)
    VALUES ('$order_number','$order_name','$order_phone','$order_email','$order_address', NOW())";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $msg1 = "Item-Ordered-Succesfully.";
        header("Location: ../checkout.php?msg=$msg1");
        emptyCart();
        exit();
    } else {
        $msg2 = "Please-try-again.";
        header("Location: ../checkout.php?msg=$msg2");
        exit();
    }
    
}
else {
    header ("Location: ../index.php");
    exit();
}
```

this process will insert the form value on the **ORDERS TABLE** but the cart still have the product.

Comment: why are you having trouble? What are you trying? Are you using transactions (i.e. you probably should be)? For 2nd Problem have you seen the [INSERT ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) syntax?

Comment: i am trying to clear the cart data after they successfully checkout on my page.

Comment: answer the questions. It looks like you want someone to write it for you. this is a help site, not a free coding solicitation site.

Comment: How are you trying to delete the items in the cart currently?

Comment: @danblack i am actually looking for a code. i posted it here because i hope that someone would give me the code to solve this problem. i tried using some functions, also tried delete query if the insert query is successful. sorry about this but im still trying to learn php. thanks for your comment btw.

Comment: @fyrye thanks for your comment. i am using $sql = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE cart_id = $cart_id"; but this one works only in the button on my cart page. i wanted to empty the cart after the successful checkout on my page.

Comment: Please update your question with the code that determines "successful checkout" along with what you have tried to accomplish your goal. See the  [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: If the DELETE was in the same SQL transaction as the INSERT INTO orders then you wouldn't get an order without the cart being deleted. Avoid mixing mysqli and pdo and use http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php arguments to avoid SQL injection

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== TRUE`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Comment: Your main issue appears to be `$cID = $_SESSION['cID'];` uses a session, but your session has not been started on this page use `if (!session_id()) { session_start(); }` before accessing the `$_SESSION` variable. However it appears to have been passed as `$cID = $_POST['customer_id'];`, So you could opt to pass it to the function as an argument `emptyCart($cID);` instead. Lastly, not sure how `$this` is defined when using `$this->conn`. You would need to pass `$conn` to the function as well.

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to delete the data in my CART column when the checkout is successful by adding multiple query in my $sql.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (order_number, order_name, order_phone, order_email, order_address, order_date)
VALUES ('$order_number','$order_name','$order_phone','$order_email','$order_address', NOW()); DELETE FROM cart WHERE customer_id = $cID";
```

and changing this code 
**from**

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
```

**into**

```
if ($conn->multi_query($sql)) {
```

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST['checkout-submit'])) {
    $cID = $_POST['customer_id'];
    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $order_Fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['order_Fname']);
    $order_Lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['order_Lname']);
    $order_name = $order_Fname .' '. $order_Lname;

    $order_number = 'PSAU000';

    $order_phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['order_phone']);
    $order_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['order_email']);

    $order_Addrs = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['order_Addrs']);
    $order_Addrs2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['order_Addrs2']);
    $pro = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pro']);
    $mun = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mun']);
    $bar = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['bar']);
    $order_address = $order_Addrs .', '. $order_Addrs2 .', '. $pro .', '. $mun .', '. $bar;
    
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (order_number, order_name, order_phone, order_email, order_address, order_date)
    VALUES ('$order_number','$order_name','$order_phone','$order_email','$order_address', NOW()); DELETE FROM cart WHERE customer_id = $cID";

    // $sql. = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE customer_id = $cID"; 

    if ($conn->multi_query($sql)) {
        $msg1 = "Item-Ordered-Succesfully.";
        header("Location: ../checkout.php?msg=$msg1");
        exit();
    } else {
        $msg2 = "Please-try-again.";
        header("Location: ../checkout.php?msg=$msg2");
        exit();
    }
    
}
else {
    header ("Location: ../index.php");
    exit();
}
```

thank you for the previous comments i will try to study those PDO and about the sql injection.